# Python for loop calls a function that calls another function

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a for loop to iterate over a list of switches.
For each device in switch_list, I call function1.
Function1 then calls function2.
However, that's when the processing ends.
I need to get back to the for loop so that I can process switch2, switch3, etc...

Here is the output:

*We are in main*

*We are in function1 and the device name is switch1*

*We are in function2 and the device name is switch1*

Here is my code:

```
switch_list = ['switch1', 'switch2']

def main():
    print('We are in main')
    for device in switch_list:
        main_action = function1(device)
        return(device)

def function1(device):
    print(f'We are in function1 and the device name is {device}')
    function1_action = function2(device)

def function2(device):
    print(f'We are in function2 and the device name is {device}')
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: remove or dedent `return(device)` and your code will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `return()` statement in your main function is inside the for loop. Your problem would be solved if you take it out of the for loop.

`return()` symbolizes the end of a function. So when your code sees the return statement, it exits main() and you get output for only the first device.

You can create a list of the devices since you are running a for loop and pass it on after it's completion.

Something like this:

```
def main():
    main_output_list = []
    print("We are in main")
    for device in switches:
        main_action = function1(device)
        main_output_list.append(output of main)
    return(main_output_list)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I took the return(device) line out of the main function and it is now working as expected. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Alexander, the return keyword exits the function, returning a provided value to the place where the method was called.

ex.

```
def give_10():
    return 10
    print("I am unreachable because I am after a return statement")

print(give_10())  # give_10() returns 10 which makes the statement 
                  # as print(10). Which in turn processes the value and prints to stdout.
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I took the return(device) line out of the main function and it is now working as expected. Cheers.